# How to index data from mongodb to solr 4.7

Tags: mongodb, solr, dataimporthandler

Does anyone know how to index data from mongodb into solr i've followed previous procedure which was mentioned  [here](https://github.com/james75/SolrMongoImporter)

can anyone give a step by step procedure to fix this issue,

here the scripts

on mydataconfig.xml

```
<dataConfig>
 <dataSource name="MyMongo" type="MongoDataSource" database="test" />
 <document name="Products">
     <entity processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
             query="{'Active':1}"
             collection="testusers"
             datasource="MyMongo"
             transformer="MongoMapperTransformer" >
         <field column="name"           name="name"       mongoField="name"/>
         <field column="position"     name="position" mongoField="position"/>

     </entity>
 </document>
```

and in solrconfig.xml

```
  <lib dir="../../lib/" regex="solr-mongo-importer.jar" />
<lib dir="../../lib/" regex="mongo.jar" />
```

......

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">mydataconfig.xml</str>

</lst> </requestHandler>
```

Note: when i checked in solr\admin (in console)

`GET:http://localhost:8983/solr/suggest/admin/ping?action=status&wt=json&_=1417082932028 : 503 service not available"`

and in dataimport section
TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined in dataimport.js

it works well for other cores i've created in same solr which connects to mysql db.